# 9V to 12V using UC3843

Tags: power-supply

So, right, I'm trying to get 3A at 12V from a 4A 9V wall adapter. I'm trying to build a SMPS for that and I've got my eyes on the IC mentioned because it looks promising (let me know if it's not the best), and I can't find anything on how to do it, so any schematics and and how to calculate the values for them would be great, and yes, i looked in the datasheet
is this okay?
[image]

IC datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25562/STMICROELECTRONICS/UC3843.html

http://danyk.cz/univ_m_en.html

Comment: You might get 2.7 amps. Nobody knows what is best for you. Nobody's going to supply schematics and the calculations. YOU need to propose a circuit idea and then you might expect some answers. You won't get 100% efficiency. Focus, Focus.

Comment: okay yeah I may have forgotten about efficiency, and 2.7A is also okay. is this circuit okay http://danyk.cz/univ_m_en.html ? if so what should i use for the current limit resitor to achieve that current?

Comment: Post the circuit into your question body and provide a link to the original source. We tend to do things professionally on this site. Also make a hyperlink to the chip's data sheet.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be easier (and cheaper) to buy a 12V adaptor?

Comment: gosh darn am I stupid, i didin't even realize those existed! you can all make fun of me if you want